# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una matriz en zig zag de esta forma? en c++

Tags: c++

Me gustaria saber si me pueden explicar como puedo recorrer una matriz de la siguiente forma. Inicia en la casilla "Inicio" y comienza avanzando por la linea roja (donde no hay linea roja es porque son casillas que el jugador no debe pasar. Les agradzco mucho su ayuda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. Aclaro ya tengo rellenada la matriz, sin embargo cuando tiro el dado y llego a la ultima casilla de lafila 0 no se como validar que el jugador no pase por las null para recorrer por las casillas validas con el numero que arrojó el dado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola se me ocurre este metodo para que hagas tu matriz, consta de dos pasos algo sencillos, el primero es recorrer toda la matriz con dos for anidados, pero en el segundo establecer los saltos en dos es decir i+=2 esto para que vaya intercalando las filas y llenandolas con lo que quieras, un ejemplo es es:

```
int matriz[9][9] = {
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

//llena las filas
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
       for (int j =0; j < 9; j+=2)
       { 
          matriz[i][j] = 1;
       }     
}
```

bien una vez ya tenemos las filas solo hace falta agregar los "puentes" entre las filas, lo logramos con el mismo procedimiento pero con el segundo bucle comenzado por 1 e igual los saltos en i+=2 pero esta vez vamos a ocupar las filas no afectadas, seguido hacemos dos variables izq y der que guardan la primera y ultima casilla, en mi ejemplo seria el 0 y el 8, luego creamos una varible booleana para intercalar que casilla si y que casilla no, y un if dentro del bucle para intercambiar dicho valor, quedaria tal que asi:

```
 int izq=0, der=8;
bool flag=true;
//agrega las esquinas
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
       for (int j =1; j < 9; j+=2)
       { 
          if(flag){
            matriz[der][j] = 1;
            flag = false;
          } else{
            matriz[izq][j] = 1;
            flag = true;
          }
       }     
}
```

y listo! tenemos la matriz en forma de zig zag, recomiendo colocar las dimensiiones de la matriz en variables para hacerlo automatico en una funcion, ahora solo falta mostrarla!!

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        std::cout << matriz[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

output:

```
111111111
000000001
111111111
100000000
111111111
000000001
111111111
100000000
```

Mi ejemplo quedo diferente del tuyo porque use una matriz 9X9

Comment: Hola! me quedo claro su ejemplo, se lo agradezco. De casualidad, me podría ayudar en esta situación: tengo un jugador que debe ir recoriendo las casillas según el dado se lo indique (por las casillas que en este caso usted indicó como "1",) como puedo hacer para que el siga ese orden en la matriz? muchas gracias

Comment: O de otra forma digamos, si estoy en el último 1 [0][8], y el dado me dice avance 2 como valido que el siga porque cayyó en casilla 0, cuando tiene que caer en casilla 1?

Comment: bueno se me ocurre que al lanzar los datos, recorras la matriz con saltos i+=2 en las filas, entonces el jugador "avanza" mientras el valor de la casilla sea jugable osea en mi ejemplo sea "1"  y la suma de la casilla mas las restantes sea menor a 9 y el sobrante lo avanza en  la fila de abajo, asi algo sencillo si buscas al mas practico te aconsejo formular luego otra pregunta mas precisa, no olvides votar por las preguntas, un saludo

Comment: y disculpa, de esta forma tambien podría jugar con los1 esquineros? realmente me urge terminar el trabajo, disculpa el abuso. Y sí, ya voté por las preguntas. Muchas gracias